# Make phone call by using UIApplication sharedApplication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sms, uiapplication

I made a button, and link the button to the following openPhone method.
But it didn't work. Error message shows "Thread 1:Program received signal: "SIGABRT".".

Should I do anything else that I do not know to let it work? Thanks

```
-(IBAction)openPhone{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://+886227637978"]];
}
```

Comment: I don't think the crash is happening because of this method of yours. Can you show the message displayed in your console?

Answer (score 4):

try this:-
self.phone is NSString that contain phone number.

```
    NSString *telephoneString=[self.phone stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSMutableString *str1=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:telephoneString];
    [str1 setString:[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""]];
    [str1 setString:[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""]];
    [str1 setString:[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]];
    [str1 setString:[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]];
    telephoneString = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:str1];
    [str1 release];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telephoneString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)openPhone:(id)sender{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://+886227637978"]];
}
```

You may also need to remove the + in tel:// . I haven't tested any of this though.
The phone number also looks kind of long. Maybe it is just a country thing though.

Also be sure that it is connected in your IB and is specified in your .h